# Can't build conda with heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, anaconda, conda

Im trying to build my flask app on heroku using apt buildpack to install tesseract and conda buildpack to install opencv. I have no problem with installing tesseract but when heroku is building conda it returns an error:

```
remote: -----> Python/Conda app detected
remote: -----> Preparing Python/Miniconda Environment
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/6ab88f205ef3af83c361b836b23ad30ba554d25ca2a0840d618de121813495d6f9f2649402a436b47e732c3409bee8f64a573c8a3fd195ed7dce30b51e134be9/bin/step
s/conda_compile: line 7: conda: command not found
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python/Conda app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I was trying to use several different conda buildpacks(official too) and buildpack sequence but it always return same error. 
My buildpacks:

```
1. heroku-community/apt
2. heroku/python
3. https://github.com/trib3/conda-buildpack.git
```

As i said I was trying different sequence of this buildpacks. 
Files in root folder: **Procfile, requirements.txt, conda-requirements.txt** and **environment.yml.**

Comment: Why do you need the Apt buildpack? What's the content of your `Aptfile`? Don't install the Python and Conda buildpack together. The Conda buildpack doesn't seem to be maintained.

Comment: Like i said, i use apt to install tesseract